# DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE returning error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am attempting to write a basic PL/SQL For Loop and keep getting an error. My statement is:

```
begin

  for tab_x in
    (select unique table_name from all_tables
     where owner like 'MSGCENTER_DBO%'
       and table_name like 'MSG_DETAIL%')
  loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tab_x);
  end loop;

end;
/
```

The error message is

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'
ORA-06550: line 6, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I am probably missing something VERY obvious but have not been able to get this to work.  I appreciate any help!

Comment: `tab_x` is of record data type and `put_line()` doesn't accept records. You need a variable of `varchar2` data type a a type that can be implicitly or explicitly converted to one. You need to pass `table_name` to the `put_line()` function using dot notation. `put_line(tab_x.table_name)`

Answer (score 4):

You want to access `tab_x.table_name` instead.

```
begin

   for tab_x in
    (select unique table_name from all_tables
     where owner like 'MSGCENTER_DBO%'
       and table_name like 'MSG_DETAIL%')
   loop
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tab_x.table_name );
  end loop;

end;
/
```